# Best way to implement abstract classes in Python

Tags: python-3.x, oop, design-patterns, abstract-class, pep8

What is the best way to implement abstract classes in Python?

This is the main approach I have seen:

```
class A(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass
```

However, it does not prevent from calling the abstract method when you extend that class.

In Java you get an error if you try to do something similar, but not in Python:

```
class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        super().foo()
B().foo() # does not raise an error
```

In order to replicate the same Java's behaviour, you could adopt this approach:

```
class A(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

However, in practice I have rarely seen this latter solution, even if is apparently the most correct one. Is there a specific reason to prefer the first approach rather than the second one ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want the error to be raised if one of the subclasses try to call the superclass abstract method, then, yes, you should raise it manually. (and then, create an instance of the Exception class to the raise command `raise NotImplementedError()` even if it works with the class directly)

However, the existing behavior is actually convenient: if your abstractmethod contains just a `pass`, then you can have any number of sub-classes inheriting your base class, and as long as at least one implements the abstractmethod, it will work. Even if all of them call the super() equivalent method, without checking anything else.

If an error - `NotImplementedError` or any other, would be called, in a complex hierarchy, making use of mixins, and such, you'd need to check at each time you'd call `super` if the error was raised, just to skipt it. For the record, checking if `super()` would hit the class where method is abstract with a conditional is possible, this way:

```
if not getattr(super().foo, "__isabstractmethod__", False):
     super().foo(...)
```

Since what do you want if you reach the base of the hierarchy for a method is for it to do nothing, it is far simples if just nothing happens!

I mean, check this:

```
class A(abc.ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def validate(self, **kwargs):
        pass

class B(A):
    def validate(self, *, first_arg_for_B, second_arg_for_B=None, **kwargs):
        super().validate(**kwargs)
        # perform validation:
        ...

class C(A)
    def validate(self, *, first_arg_for_C **kwargs):
        super().validate(**kwargs)
        # perform validation:
        ...

class Final(B, C):
    ...
```

Neither `B.validate` nor `C.validate` need to worry about any other class in the hierarchy, just do their thing and pass on. 
If A.validate would raise, both methods would have to do `super().validate(...)` inside  a `try: ...;except  ...:pass`  statement, or inside a weird `if` block, for the gain of...nothing.

**update** - I just found this note on the oficial documentation:

> **Note** Unlike Java abstract methods, these abstract methods may have an
>   implementation. This implementation can be called via the super()
>   mechanism from the class that overrides it. This could be useful as an
>   end-point for a super-call in a framework that uses cooperative
>   multiple-inheritance.
>   https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod

I will even return you a personal question, if you can reply in the comments: I understand it is much less relevant in Java where one can't have multiple inheritance, so, even in a big hierarchy, the first subclass to implement the abstract method would usually be well known. But otherwise, in a Java project were one could pick one of various Base concrete classes, and proceed with others in an arbitrary order, since the abstractmethod raises, how is that resolved?

Comment: thanks for the reply: your example is really clear.

Basically, you are saying that the child class should always be able to call the parent class regardless of the type abstract or not. right?

It s a way you honour the single responsibility principle. right?

If a child class: B, overrides the abstract method of class:A by simply calling it, it s fine because it means that class B does not have the responsibility to do further things. right?


I would like to answer your question, but I did not understand the problem. what do you mean with "pick one class" and "proceed with others?"

Comment: "Pick one class" is: pick one of possibly various concrete implementations of an abstract class to be the first in the inheritance hierarchy. And "proceed with others" is taking other such concrete class implementations to continue the inheritance hierarchy until one gets to the implementation that will be really used, some levels bellow.